# Wallch for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wallch

Wondering if there is a working version of Wallch for 16.04 x64?
The package available doesn't seem to work - runs, but will not even show the pictures in the config...
Thanks.

Comment: in preferences in wallch, i changed from MATE to GNOME and now it works. before, i would activate live earth and nothing would happen. once i made that change and closed and reopened wallch it now works.

Answer (score 0):

The version in the default repositories is not currently compatible with 16.04.
It installs but doesn't actually work once you set it up.

Adding the repository ppa:wallch/wallch-daily in 16.04 returns a
"This PPA does not support xenial" error.

Install Wallch from this page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=wallch

Under Download "wallch" just click the APT install button and follow the installer on screen.

Alternatively you can download the 64 bit deb package and install manually with

```
sudo dpkg -i wallch_4.0-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but link only answers are discouraged. Please edit and explain the steps. Give me a nudge when you do that so I can upvote.

Comment: I have no idea what the purpose of ubuntuupdates.org is, it always looks like a scam site for people who don't know their way around the official pages and it has ads. The package it offers is from the official repository, so I don't see a point in downloading manually.

Comment: I find it strange that this says the version from the repositories is not compatible, and then suggests downloading from those very same repositories! **`xenial` is 16.04**.

Answer (score 0):

I have it running and displaying BitDay-2 though out the day since it was posted on OMG Ubuntu. I wouldn't say it runs flawless, but once it's configured and I ticked *Wallpapers* on the indicator menu it started cycling the wallpapers I set.

Can you elaborate on the issue you are having?

---

Edit: Okay this is tricky, here is what I'm currently doing to have wallpapers cycle with this tool and working around it's current flaws:

1. Open the application, select the directory in wallpapers, then got to settings an configure the specific interval you want to use as the higher value, and a lower value, it should automatically set the higher value as default.
2. Close the application.
3. Open the application with `wallch --start`, you can do that in Unity via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Only cycle the wallpapers through the indicator menu items previous or next now.